# Tensorflow 2.4.0 import error cannot import name 'multi_worker_mirrored_2x1_cpu'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, importerror

I'm getting an error upon loading tensorflow==2.4.0 in Python. I've tried uninstall and reverting to an earlier version (but still 2), but can't seem to be able to solve it. Anyone any idea? The full error is:

````
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\CX667CJ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from ._api.v2 import __internal__
  File "C:\Users\CX667CJ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from . import distribute
  File "C:\Users\CX667CJ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\distribute\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import combinations
  File "C:\Users\CX667CJ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\distribute\combinations\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_combinations import multi_worker_mirrored_2x1_cpu
ImportError: cannot import name 'multi_worker_mirrored_2x1_cpu' from 'tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_combinations' (C:\Users\CX667CJ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\strategy_combinations.py)```
````

Answer (score 0):

I saw similar issue today

> from tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_combinations import
> multi_worker_mirrored_2x1_cpu ImportError: cannot import name
> 'multi_worker_mirrored_2x1_cpu' from
> 'tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_combinations'
> (C:\Users\sharm\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\strategy_combinations.py)

I checked out the file and could not locate 'multi_worker_mirrored_2x1_cpu'.
Looked into tensorflow repo on git. this file was present there.
So **I considered reinstalling tensorflow (use virtualenv if you don't)**, closed my program and **restarted everything**. I no longer got this issue now.

Also consider,

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu --user
```

version = 2.4.1

Let me know if this resolves your issue as well.