# solution to tensorflow import error after import module

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
pip install tensorflow
#== import it 
import tensorflow as tf
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\C1Manager\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\dani\comp-vision\ld dataset\try.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\C1Manager\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from ._api.v2 import __internal__
  File "C:\Users\C1Manager\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from . import distribute
  File "C:\Users\C1Manager\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\distribute\__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import combinations
  File "C:\Users\C1Manager\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\__internal__\distribute\combinations\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_combinations import parameter_server_strategy_1worker_2ps_1gpu
ImportError: cannot import name 'parameter_server_strategy_1worker_2ps_1gpu' from 'tensorflow.python.distribute.strategy_combinations' (C:\Users\C1Manager\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\strategy_combinations.py)
```

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65320835/tensorflow-2-4-0-import-error-cannot-import-name-multi-worker-mirrored-2x1-cpu

Comment: Why dont use anaconda?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Tensorflow not installed properly, uninstall existing Tensorflow and install new one by following instructions,

**Using PIP**

```
#Install tensorflow using pip virtual env 
$pip install virtualenv
$virtualenv tf   # tf is virtual env name
$source tf/bin/activate
tf $ pip install tensorflow
tf $ python
>>import tensorflow as tf
>>tf.__version__
2.5.0
```

**Using anaconda**

```
1. Set Up Anaconda Environments
conda create --name tf_env python=3

2. Activate the new Environment
source activate tf_env

3. Install Tensorflow
pip install tensorflow
```